# Get event when replacing node with the same value?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is it possible to get an event in a Listener when I replace value of a node with the same value? seams like if firebase notice that the value is the same no event accures..:s

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question. I wrote an answer below, but that unfortunately also has to be equally broad (and a bit theoretical). If you want a more concrete answer, it helps if you share the [minimal code that reproduces  the problem you have](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Database synchronizes state between clients. If a write operation doesn't change the state, there is nothing to synchronize to the other listening clients.

In simple code:

```
ref.setValue(1);
ref.setValue(1); // won't trigger listeners
ref.setValue(2); // will trigger active listeners
ref.setValue(2); // won't trigger listeners
```

It sounds like you want to instead pass messages between clients. This is totally feasible, but means that you should model your data differently. Instead of storing the value in your database, store the fact that the client wrote a value.

In simple code:

```
ref.push(1);
ref.push(1);
ref.push(2);
ref.push(2);
```

In this last sample each write will trigger listeners on `ref`, since each write is new.

This is a common pattern: instead of storing the final state, you're storing the state changes. It essentially similar the mechanism behind oplogs in databases and many other systems.

Answer (score 1):

Because nothing happens there is no event that is triggered. What can you do in stead, is to check the value before you are setting it.

```
if(myValue.equals(firebaseValue)) {
    //do something 
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ty doesn't help exacly beacuse it's a service that puts in value and client (mobile) listenes to results and even if the value is the same I want to be notify is service is done sith the proces and it's a new value (ofc there is a walk around that by creating new node with time stemp or something that changes as soons results from service came -but just seams like pain in the a'**:S) thank you nevertheless:)